# Creating an instance of a user defined data type in a stored procedure

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a postgres function where it returns a data type, a data type that was user-defined, I am modifying the function by removing a function call, that returned that user-defined object.  I now need to create an instance of that object in that stored procedure, and I am not sure how to do so, any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Some details would be useful. The type definition, for a start. You should also include your PostgreSQL version. Right now, Erwin's semi-serious answer is the best you'll get.

Answer (score 0):

The simples way to create an "instance of that object":

```
NULL::name_of_composite_type
```

For more, you'll need to provide (a lot) more details in the question.